# VBA Excel separate range of date in cells

Tags: excel, vba, date

This is giving me a headache.. Im trying to do the following:

This is the data I have, I have element's names and a start date and an end date.
I want to have this data by day and not in range anymore (So I can upload it to a database I have which is by day).

I dont know if I can do this without using VBA but I guess the quickes would be VBA.

Current data:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ name  ║ start date ║  end date  ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ foo1  ║ 25-11-2013 ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo2  ║ 25-11-2013 ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo3  ║ 25-11-2013 ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo4  ║ 25-11-2013 ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo5  ║ 25-11-2013 ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo6  ║ 28-11-2013 ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo7  ║ 28-11-2013 ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo8  ║ 28-11-2013 ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo9  ║ 28-11-2013 ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo10 ║ 28-11-2013 ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo11 ║ 29-11-2013 ║ 30-11-2013 ║
║ foo12 ║ 29-11-2013 ║ 30-11-2013 ║
║ foo13 ║ 29-11-2013 ║ 30-11-2013 ║
║ foo14 ║ 29-11-2013 ║ 30-11-2013 ║
║ foo15 ║ 29-11-2013 ║ 30-11-2013 ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

And I want to separate de names by day, to obtain this:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╗
║ name  ║    date    ║
╠═══════╬════════════╣
║ foo1  ║ 25-11-2013 ║
║ foo2  ║ 25-11-2013 ║
║ foo3  ║ 25-11-2013 ║
║ foo4  ║ 25-11-2013 ║
║ foo5  ║ 25-11-2013 ║
║ foo1  ║ 26-11-2013 ║
║ foo2  ║ 26-11-2013 ║
║ foo3  ║ 26-11-2013 ║
║ foo4  ║ 26-11-2013 ║
║ foo5  ║ 26-11-2013 ║
║ foo1  ║ 27-11-2013 ║
║ foo2  ║ 27-11-2013 ║
║ foo3  ║ 27-11-2013 ║
║ foo4  ║ 27-11-2013 ║
║ foo5  ║ 27-11-2013 ║
║ foo6  ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo7  ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo8  ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo9  ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo10 ║ 28-11-2013 ║
║ foo11 ║ 29-11-2013 ║
║ foo12 ║ 29-11-2013 ║
║ foo13 ║ 29-11-2013 ║
║ foo14 ║ 29-11-2013 ║
║ foo15 ║ 29-11-2013 ║
║ foo11 ║ 30-11-2013 ║
║ foo12 ║ 30-11-2013 ║
║ foo13 ║ 30-11-2013 ║
║ foo14 ║ 30-11-2013 ║
║ foo15 ║ 30-11-2013 ║
╚═══════╩════════════╝
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: +1 for a well-formatted question! How did you create that table format for the post? It's nice and readable :)

Comment: These text-like tables should be standardized for Excel questions demanding samples... Excellent.

Comment: You can do this just using copy/paste...  but once you separate them, how do you know whether the date is a start date or an end date? Doesn't that matter?  This seems like it should be two fields, not one.

Comment: Are the start and end dates in the same column?  Are you simply trying to extract the start dates?

Comment: @Blackhawk [link](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)

Comment: @DavidZemens There wont be start date and end date since, it will by data of one day, not a range.

Comment: @James they are in different columns, and I want to separate them into days, so if name "foo" was from monday to friday, I want to have 5 rows with name "foo" with date, monday, tusday..friday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way might be to use VBA. The following code loops through the values from column `A` and `C`, writes these underneath the existing data in column `A` and `B` and removes data in column `C`.

```
Sub SeperateDateRange()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim nCol As Integer

    'Define sheet
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    nCol = 1 '<~~ Defines the number of columns before the date columns

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Loops throuh cells
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, nCol + 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1 Step 1
        For j = 0 To Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 2).Value - Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 1).Value Step 1

            With Ws.Cells(Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
                For k = 0 To nCol - 1 Step 1
                    .Offset(0, k).Value = Ws.Cells(i + 1, k + 1).Value
                Next k
                .Offset(0, nCol).Value = DateSerial(Year(Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 1).Value), Month(Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 1).Value), Day(Ws.Cells(i + 1, nCol + 1).Value) + j)
            End With
        Next j
    Next i

    'Deletes last column with dates
    Ws.Cells(1, nCol + 2).EntireColumn.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:** Because of a follow-up question in the comments, the code is now changed so that the variable `nCol` defines the number of columns with names before the date columns. If the macro should run on the data presented in the original question, then `nCol = 1`. If there are three columns with names before the date viables, then `nCol = 3`.

Comment: You're missing the between dates days. if I have a row with name "foo" from "25-11-2013" to "27-11-2013" Then the result woudl be three rows named "foo" with date "25-11-2013","26-11-2013" and "27-11-2013"

Comment: I see - I have updated the code. Hopefully this will get the job done.

Comment: srrry to ask again but what if I had more columns (name1, name2, name3 ) before thedates. where should I add them in the code?

Comment: It depends on how you would want them to to be listed in your final table. Do you want `Name1`, `Name2` and `Name3` all to be in the same column?

Comment: no, different columns.. the same you did but having more columns with information before de date, the ouput is the same information columns and the date column

Comment: Sorry about the late answer. I have updated the code above. I have included a variable `nCol`. You can use this to set the number of columns before the date variables. I.e. in the case where you got three name-columns you should run the code with `nCol = 3`.

Answer (score 1):

Combined with @SorenHoltenHansen's answer, this should get you where you want to go.  This class will accept a Start and End date range and it will calculate the full range of dates which you can then use in code.

Create a new class, call it "clsDateRange", and add the following code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private m_colDates As Collection

Public Sub InitStartEnd(ByVal dtStart As Date, ByVal dtEnd As Date)
    Set m_colDates = New Collection
    Dim tempDate As Date
    For tempDate = dtStart To dtEnd Step 1
        m_colDates.Add DateValue(tempDate)
    Next
End Sub

Public Property Get Dates() As Collection
    Set Dates = m_colDates
End Property
```

You can go whole hog and implement the collection interface, but this should be sufficient for your needs.  If you are going to have very large date ranges and you want to be smart about it, you could store just the start and end dates and generate the in-between dates only when they are needed, but I wanted to be able to use the For...Each without having to define [_NewEnum] and all of the subproperties of Collection.

Here are a few tests in a module "mdlMain" so you can see how you might use it:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim oDateRange As New clsDateRange
    Dim varDate As Variant

    oDateRange.InitStartEnd "25-11-2013", "27-11-2013"
    For Each varDate In oDateRange.Dates()
        MsgBox varDate
    Next

    oDateRange.InitStartEnd "28-11-2013", "28-11-2013"
    For Each varDate In oDateRange.Dates()
        MsgBox varDate
    Next

    oDateRange.InitStartEnd "29-11-2013", "30-11-2013"
    For Each varDate In oDateRange.Dates()
        MsgBox varDate
    Next

End Sub
```

---

Incidentally, [dates are actually just 64-bit floating point numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278460.aspx), [Doubles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). They represent [the range January 1, 100 to December 31, 9999](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278460.aspx). Each day is 1, so the entire range is [-657434, 2958465]. Times of day are represented as fractional decimal parts.  Midnight is *.0, noon is *.5, 3:30 is ~ *.645833333333333.  Currently (in my timezone), it's December 6, 2013 1:27 PM.  According to VBA in the immediate window `?CDbl(now())`, that's 41614.5608680556.

So that's the reason why I can run through the date range in a for loop, adding one each time to increment the day.