# VBA separate range of dates in cells with duration

Tags: excel, vba

The code from Søren Holten Hansen under  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428227/vba-excel-separate-range-of-date-in-cells/27102966) actually has part of my answer, but not completely.

I need to split dates along with their respective duration.

example: 
Begin Date     End Date    Duration
3-Nov              5-Nov            2.5

**I need it to look like this:**
3-Nov     1
4-Nov     1
5-Nov     0.5

I need the half day to be shown on the last day. I am not sure how to make this split.
Appreciate the help this forum provides. This will really save my life!!!

**my code:**

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(AND(RC[-4]=R[-1]C[-4],RC[-4]=R[1]C[-4]),R[-1]C[-2]-R[-1]C, IF(R[-1]C[-2]=R[-1]C,R[-1]C[-2], R[-1]C[-2]))"
    Range("E21").Select

Thank you,
Marvin.

Comment: Have you tried it on your own with the help of the post?

Comment: marvin this is not a code writing site :) I would recommend that you give it a try on your own and then post the code that you tried and then we will help you...

Comment: yes, apologies. i have tried it and unsuccessful. posting my code now

Comment: @PareshJ : as you can see im quite a novice at this and need some serious help. My code is basically a formula. thats the only way i could do it and i'm sure there is a better method.
please help! :(

Comment: @SiddharthRout - could you kindly help me, i've been struggling now for 5 hours without any break through mate

Answer (score 0):

Following code may help to solve your problem.

```
'Function print_date
' 1st argument: date of period begin
' 2nd argument: date of period end
' 3rd argument: duration in days
'
' CAUTION: This code does not check consistency between dates and duration.
'    If you set duration 1.5 between Nov-3 to Nov-5, this code raise no error
'    and you may see duration -0.5 on Nov-5.
Function print_date(beginDay, endDay, duration) As Integer
  Dim aDay As Date
  Dim row As Integer

  row = 1
  For aDay = beginDay To endDay
   Cells(row, 1) = aDay 'set date on first column
    If duration > 1# Then
      Cells(row, 2) = 1 'set 1 on second column because more one day left.
    Else 'Duration is less than one day
      Cells(row, 2) = duration
    End If
    duration = duration - 1#
    row = row + 1
  Next aDay

End Function

' Test routine I checked operation of print_date.
Sub test_print_date()
 Dim a As Long

 a = print_date(DateValue("2014/11/03"), DateValue("2014/11/05"), 2.5)


End Sub
```

You may see the output on the cells A1:B3 when you run 'test_print_date()' of avobe code.

Comment: thank you for the code, i tried it but it didnt work.

Comment: Whoops! Letter 'F' was lacked from 'Function'. Could you try corrected code?

Comment: I caught that when trying the code but it didnt help.
your function just splits based on the hard coded 2.5.
the 2.5 i mentioned was just an example.

so imagine this:
column A - start date
column B - end date
column C - days duration

so using the above format, there are multiple rows with begin and end dates and corresponding durations.
i need to split the dates up and assign the duration next to the split-up date.
i hope i'm explaining this better?

Comment: I separate data and function. In function 'print_date', there is no hard coded dates and duration. I wrote subroutine 'test_print_date' for showing an example to use 'print_date'. In that subroutine, date of begining, date of end and duration are hard corded.  You can modify code in 'test_print_date()' as you like.

Comment: frankly i don't know how to do it :(
 i'm assuming i need to somehow loop through the code till an empty cell is found?